# 馅饼 in Cantonese

Tags: word-choice, cantonese

In the Dim Sum place I usually go to (in the U.S), they call the pan-fried bun stuffed with Chinese chive and shrimp 韭菜馅饼.

I came from Northern China and the shape and size of that bun are, by any standard, 包子 rather than 馅饼.

I wonder if this is normal in Cantonese or just that restaurant.

If it's normal, is the distinction between 包子 and 馅饼 cooking method (pan-fried vs. steamed) rather than shape and size?

Comment: I have seen those before too. It's possible that 馅饼 has come to mean any pan-fried pastry with fillings. Were they flat on both sides or just on one side?

Comment: @JamesJiao they look just like 生煎包. Maybe both sides are cooked but the bottom is apparently pan-fried much deeper than the upper side.

Comment: Can you post a couple of pictures?

Comment: @trideceth12 Found this picture on Yelp, on the plate to the leftmost. http://s3-media4.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/W8e5f37JGPXZVOrSJJmT-w/l.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah. 包 (usually sans 子, most of the time, or sometimes as 包仔, and sometimes as 鮑[仔]) is a steamed bun, whereas 餡餅 is baked/pan-fried.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you be explicit on whether shape is a factor or not?

Comment: I don't think shape is much of a factor, really... I'll look at some menus in the coming days and see if I can bring some examples.